# Binding last item of an ObservableCollection to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, binding

I'm currently trying to setup an application that will allow me to display data output from a COM port, all of it being numbers. as I'm still relatively new to C# I wanted to start of by creating some SampleData for my class:

```
<vm:SensorViewModel xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MEMS_Analyzer.Content.Data">
    <vm:SensorViewModel.Items>
        <vm:SensorData  id="0" accelX="-0.154" accelY="-0.557" accelZ="0.770" gyroX="6.280" gyroY="3.902" gyroZ="-1.280" magnetoX="18.600" magnetoY="14.399" magnetoZ="45.599" airPressure="1017.095" airTemp="32.48" />
        <vm:SensorData  id="1" accelX="-0.150" accelY="-0.357" accelZ="1.270" gyroX="6.180" gyroY="4.002" gyroZ="-1.270" magnetoX="18.300" magnetoY="14.339" magnetoZ="45.500" airPressure="1016.095" airTemp="32.28" />
        <vm:SensorData  id="2" accelX="-0.164" accelY="-1.557" accelZ="0.270" gyroX="6.580" gyroY="2.902" gyroZ="-2.280" magnetoX="17.900" magnetoY="15.399" magnetoZ="40.549" airPressure="1017.790" airTemp="32.38" />
        <vm:SensorData  id="3" accelX="-1.154" accelY="-0.724" accelZ="0.218" gyroX="4.213" gyroY="3.342" gyroZ="-1.234" magnetoX="11.632" magnetoY="14.334" magnetoZ="38.523" airPressure="1017.534" airTemp="32.48" />
        <vm:SensorData  id="5" accelX="-1.987" accelY="-0.307" accelZ="1.770" gyroX="8.280" gyroY="1.902" gyroZ="-0.280" magnetoX="20.600" magnetoY="13.399" magnetoZ="40.599" airPressure="1030.095" airTemp="33.48" />
    </vm:SensorViewModel.Items>
</vm:SensorViewModel>
```

I setup a new page with a grid that I can succesfully navigate to like this:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">  
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel MinWidth="200">
                <TextBlock Text="ACCELERATION" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

My issue right now is that I want to have a TextBlock displaying me the last Item of my Items Collection in the SensorModel. I read about creating a custom value converter, however my first tries with that didn't go so well. What would be the easiest way to bind my latest accelX, accelY and accelZ data to TextBlocks and get them to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, we generally just create whatever properties that we need to display our data the way we want it. In your case, the easiest thing to do would be to expose the last item from your collection as a property in your code behind (of course, you'd also need to define your collection there too):

```
public SensorData LastItem
{
    get { return SensorDataCollection.Last(); }
}

public ObservableCollection<SensorData> SensorDataCollection
{
    get { return sensorDataCollection; }
    set
    {
        sensorDataCollection = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SensorDataCollection"); // <-- INotifyPropertyChanged
        NotifyPropertyChanged("LastItem"); // <-- Notify LastItem change here too
    }
}
```

...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastItem}" />
```

Comment: He should tie in to the CollectionChanged event of SensorDataCollection to raise PropertyChanged for LastItem as well.

Comment: @LeeO. yeah sure... there's lots of other ways to improve this code too, but it should do as a basic example for the question author. I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Comment: My only issue with this is that when initiliazing the SensorViewModel, I get stuck in an endless loop resulting in a StackOverflow exception at the set code. I feel like an idiot for failing at these simple issues, haha

Comment: That's what debugging is for. Just step through the code until you see what else is being initialised from the constructor. Alternatively, don't initialise anything from the constructor... instantiate the object and then call something like `viewModel.Initialise()` in which you have moved the code from the constructor into. There are many solutions.

Comment: For anyone who runs into the same issues as I did: I fixed it by using a backing variable, meaning instead of `sensorDataCollection` I simply put `_sensorDataCollection`. Otherwise it starts recursively setting its own property, which results in a StackOverflow exception.